# Toggle hover from div onlick (remove hover, add it back)

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, hover, toggle

After clicking a div i want to change it's color and disable the hover. When clicked again i want it to switch to it's previous color and enable the hover again.

So i have this div:

```
<div class="leftTeam"></div>
```

Which have this hover:

```
.leftTeam {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    margin-auto;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
}

.leftTeam:hover {
    border: 1px solid #adadad;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

This  images shows the desired behaviour. Doesn't matter if it will be pure CSS code or javascript included. Thanks!

[[image: toggle style]]

Comment: add a class on click and style it

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer!

Comment: Comment is not an answer...

Comment: On http://cybbet.com/ is a list that behaves as shown above.

Comment: [Your code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5-ZV3bxMIlMY21xQ01aSWE3ZDg) contains a lot of html and css that is not needed for your question - you may take a look at [mcve help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I do not know if you are aware of it but on the [help vampire bullet list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) a few of the points apply to your current efforts. In good faith i [got you started with your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzmMqg).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function switchClass(ele){
    if(ele.className == "leftTeam"){
      ele.className+=" clicked";
      }
    else{
      ele.className = "leftTeam";
      }
    }
```

```css
    .leftTeam {
        border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
        margin-auto;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    
    .clicked:hover {
        border: 1px solid #adadad;
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        transition: 1s;
    }
```

```html
<div class="leftTeam" onclick="switchClass(this)">Click to change the class!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle style (hover, color) after click event on element:

```js
function toggleStyle(el){
    if(el.className == "initial"){
      el.className="clicked";
      }
    else{
      el.className = "initial";
      }
    }
```

```css
 div { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse}
.initial{ background-color: #efefef; }        
.initial:hover { background-color: #B4FDAB; }
.clicked { background-color: red; }

p.css3{background-color: #efefef;}
p.css3:hover{ background-color: #B4FDAB; }
p.css3:focus{background-color: #B6C2EF; }
p.css3:active{background-color: #B6C2EF; }
```

```html
<div class="initial" onclick="toggleStyle(this)">Click to change the class!</div>
<div class="initial" onclick="toggleStyle(this)">Click to change the class!</div>

<h3>Testing css 3 focus or active </h3>
<p class="css3">css 3 focus or active seem to be insufficient</p>
```

### Testing a css 3 only solution

It seems that using active or focus are not sufficient, since the hover state is not replaced

```
p.css3{background-color: #efefef;}
p.css3:hover{ background-color: #B4FDAB; }
p.css3:focus{background-color: #B6C2EF; }
p.css3:active{background-color: #B6C2EF; }
<p class="css3">css 3 focus or active</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked well except i also need to switch to it's normal design when i click on something else for example. That way it stays clicked even if i click on other button for example.

Comment: Here's a quick gif video of what i want to do exactly. Thank you again!
https://i.gyazo.com/7a7ba829d46dc7960bfa1dfaa2d3a4b3.gif

Comment: Where are you stuck to solve your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Last thing i tried was your code, but it only work the one div and doesn't switch back to normal when another div inside the same row is clicked. Here's my code:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5-ZV3bxMIlMY21xQ01aSWE3ZDg

I want to be able to click the two divs inside the teams column. When clicked in the left div for example, it should change it's color to e.g purple and switch back to normal if click it again or click on the right div. If i click one of these divs in another colum, the clicked one on the previous column should remain active. Check the gif image i provided.

Comment: Also (my previous comment was too long), the rows are expanding when click in the row itself, but i want it to expand only if i click the "LIVE NOW" link. Thank you!